# Change the position of error div to keep it on top of every section div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have long page with multiple sections.

```
<div class="section">Client Information </div>
<div class="section">Billing Information </div>
<div class="section">Contact Information </div>
```

There are multiple fields inside a div. Form receives list of errors when user submits the form. I am showing all the errors in a expand/collapse div.

Is it possible to scroll the page section by section? So that error div can remain on top of each section. Find html code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/himanshuy/cgj87/).

Comment: Its not clear Do you want the error div to be fixed at top?

Comment: I want error div to be on top of visible section when user scroll vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you want. Feel free to report the changes.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .section {
    margin: 1.250em 0;
    padding: 1.6em 0.2em 1.0em;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.sectionTitle {
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.panel-group{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2147483647;
    width:100%;
}

</style>
<div class="panel-group" id="errors">
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                Error(s)
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="active">
                            <th>Error Message</th>
                            <th>Error Code</th>
                            <th>Results</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>
<div class="section" name="ClientInfo" id="ClientInfo">
    <div class="row field sectionTitle">
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <span class="section-title">Section: Client Info </span>
                        </div>
     </div>
      <div class="row field"> <!-- row starts --->
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 form-inline"> <!-- column 2 -->
        <label class="pocLabel">
            <span style="color:red;">*</span>
        Customer First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="form-control" required="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 form-inline"> <!-- column 1 -->
        <label class="pocLabel">
            <span style="color:red;">*</span>
        Customer Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="LastName" class="form-control" required="">
      </div>
      </div> <!-- row ends -->

</div>
<div class="section" name="ClientInformation" id="ClientInformation">
    <div class="row field sectionTitle">
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <span class="section-title">Section: Address Information </span>
         </div>
     </div>
      <div class="row field"> <!-- row starts --->
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 form-inline"> <!-- column 2 -->
        <label class="pocLabel">
            <span style="color:red;">*</span>
        Street Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="form-control" required="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 form-inline"> <!-- column 1 -->
        <label class="pocLabel">
            <span style="color:red;">*</span>
        Apt</label>
    <input type="text" name="LastName" class="form-control" required="">
      </div>
      </div> <!-- row ends -->
          <div class="row field"> <!-- row starts --->
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 form-inline"> <!-- column 2 -->
        <label class="pocLabel">
            <span style="color:red;">*</span>
        City</label>
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="form-control" required="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 form-inline"> <!-- column 1 -->
        <label class="pocLabel">
            <span style="color:red;">*</span>
        Country</label>
    <input type="text" name="LastName" class="form-control" required="">
      </div>
      </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: No it didn't help. Now If you scroll down `panel-group` overlaps rest of the `section elements`. I want to come on just on top of visible `section`. I have a question: What is the difference between z-index:1 and `z-index:2147483647`?

Comment: The div setup is creating problems here. Please follow [this](http://jsfiddle.net/C7caU/21/). This will solve your issue.